# invalid syntax when trying to make a dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

```
test_list_k = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

test_list_v = ['f', 'g', 'h']

test_dict_comp = {k: v for k in test_list_k and for v in test_list_v}
print(test_dict_comp)
```

For some reason it counts the second for in test_dict_comp as invalid syntax.

Comment: Just drop the `and`

Comment: `and` in Python is a boolean operator, not a conjunction. Even if you feel like you need to say "and" when reading your code out loud, that doesn't mean you should stick an `and` operator there.

Comment: Also, that dict comprehension doesn't make sense even with the `and` fixed - dicts don't support repeated keys.

Comment: Did you mean to pair the values from one `list` with the values from the other, with the first as keys and the second as the values of the result? And if so, what are you expecting to happen with the unpaired value in `test_list_k`? Is it discarded? Given a filler value? Do you reuse a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the goal is to make a `dict` pairing keys from `test_list_k` with values from `test_list_v`, what you want is `zip` (which will drop the unpaired key), or `itertools.zip_longest` (which will allow you to provide a filler value for the unpaired key). The syntax for using it is:

```
test_dict_comp = {k: v for k, v in zip(test_list_k, test_list_v)}
```

or for this simple case (where no filtering or transformation is being done, so the comprehension isn't needed), you can just pass the resulting iterator of pairs to the `dict` constructor directly:

```
test_dict_comp = dict(zip(test_list_k, test_list_v))
```

Your code breaks because `and` is for boolean tests, it can't combine arbitrary statement fragments the way you're attempting. The parser is trying to parse the value to iterate over in the first for loop, and when it gets to `test_list_k and for` it gets confused (because `test_list_k and` must be followed by another expression to produce the other value to be tested for truthiness if `test_list_k` is determined to be truthy, and `for` is a keyword, not a legal expression for the right hand side of `and`).